# docker network - ping 255.255.255.255

Tags: docker

When I setup a network with `docker create network test1` and then start a few containers, for example

```
docker run -d --net=test1 --name=t1 elasticsearch
docker run -d --net=test1 elasticsearch
docker run -d --net=test1 elasticsearch
```

I can't broadcast ping any of these containers with `docker exec -ti t1 ping 255.255.255.255`.

Any idea how I can change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently followed in [issue 17814](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17814)

> UDP broadcasts don't work in multi-host network between hosts.
>   UDP broadcasts only work if both containers run on the same host.
>
> Playing with icmp broadcast by pinging on 255.255.255.255, I receive replies only from the local host:

```
# ping -b 255.255.255.255
WARNING: pinging broadcast address
PING 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.601 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.424 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.420 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.427 ms
```

> (I made sure `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts` is set to 0 on both hosts.)
>
> It also seems impossible to set a broadcast address on the interface connected to the shared network:

```
# ifconfig eth0 broadcast 10.0.0.255
SIOCSIFBRDADDR: Operation not permitted
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
```

---

This ability to **multicast in overlay driver** is discussed in [**`docker/libnetwork` issue 552**](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/issues/552).
(help wanted)